# How to make an image full width (like banner) on the product page of Shopify?

Tags: css, width, shopify

Im using Shopify and would like to add a full screen image on the product page. Since you cant do that from Shopify I will have to add some coding in the css of the theme. I can find the section using inspect on my page but what code is needed to overwrite the width set by the theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the product page templates/snippets from your theme editor after login into the Admin. It depends on the shopify theme you are using.

If you could share a secured preview to your products page, it will be more helpful.

But in general, you can try this:

```
 1. Login to your store admin 
 2. Go to "Themes" under "Sales Channels" in the left side bar
 3. Click "Actions" next to your current theme and click on "Edit Code"
 4. Go to "Assets" directory, you should see a file called
    "theme.scss.liquid"
```

That's where you can put your custom css to make the product image full width by inspecting the classes used.